# Visual Studio 2017 Mac: Command line arguments

Tags: mac, development, ide

1st time using/playing with VS 2017 for Mac. Where do I enter command line arguments that will be saved for use with each run?

I have found that I can enter arguments in RunWith->CustomConfiguration Arguments field, but they are not saved. I have to re enter them each time I run.

On the PC version, you can enter the CL args in the properties area and they are saved for use with each run (no need to reenter).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.

Comment: This should be open - this is narrow enough that someone that uses VS can answer or look up the answer on Microsoft’s web site. We don’t close all questions where you could look up Apple documentation, so MS should get the same treatment and this is about third party Mac software.

Comment: I have looked on the MS site and found nothing. Maybe because the Mac version is very new? Anything related to what I have asked only references the PC version. While there are basic docs on this product, there is nothing out there, that I have found, that is detailed. I was hoping someone here might know. Its a straight forward and specific question.